# Simple repository for a small/medium sized ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, repository

I am about to start a small/medium sized project. I am by no means a software architect. But I tend to question every move I make at times, since I want to do things correct.

I found a way to implement a simple repository, and I wanted to know if this is a "correct" way of doing it. I came to this solution, since I know what is going on, and not taking in something to complex before I have the knowledge.

**Unit of work**

Where I make sure I to keep all my repositories under the same dbcontext. In my UOW I can access all repos when calling it from the controller.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private ContactRepository _contactRepo;
    private ApplicationDbContext _entities;

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext entities)
    {
        _entities = entities;
    }

    public ContactRepository ContactRepo
    {
        get
        {
            if (_contactRepo == null)
            {
                _contactRepo = new ContactRepository(_entities);
            }
            return _contactRepo;
        }
    }


    public void Save()
    {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _entities.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**ContactRepository**

This is a short example of a repository, where it receives the dbcontext and uses it to grab whatever data I want.

```
   public class ContactRepository
   {
    private ApplicationDbContext _entities;

    public ContactRepository(ApplicationDbContext entities)
    {
        _entities = entities;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAll()
    {
        return _entities.Contacts;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

Short example of controller

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{

    UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(new ApplicationDbContext());

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var contacts = uow.ContactRepo.GetAll();
        return View(contacts);
    }



    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        uow.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

In this way I will have access to all my repositories under the same dbcontext which I was aiming for.

I know things can be done smarter/different. With for example a extendable generic repo. But in this case I am aiming for something simple and understandable. But still don't want to make a huge mistake, if there is a major flaw.

Do you see any major flaws with this way of handling data through entity framework?

Comment: ["The single best reason to not use the repository pattern with Entity Framework? Entity Framework already implements a repository pattern."](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/220126/123339)

Comment: i am fully aware of entity framework having a built in repo. But having EF logic scattered across controllers can lead to a fully fledged maintenance hell. :)

Comment: That answer also explains to "go with a service pattern, where you construct an API that your application can use without knowing or caring whether the data is coming from Entity Framework, NHibernate, or a Web API".

Answer (score 2):

Keep your disposables short lived and you'll *never* have to implement `IDisposable` yourself.

In other words, avoid keeping disposable objects as members. Always try to wrap them in a `using` statement. If you do that, you'll find that your Unit of Work doesn't need to be disposable.

---

I can't ignore the obvious here though. There is no reason for any of this code to exist. It literally does *nothing* but pass through to the `DbContext`. Entity Framework is already a repository & unit of work.

That's not to say that you shouldn't hide the fact that you're using EF from your controller though. It's much better to create a domain specific API to decouple your controller from the persistence. In our projects we'll often have things like `FooService.GetByName(string name)` and `FooService.GetMostRecent(int numberToRetrieve)` kinds of methods. It makes for pleasant reading and easy implementation changes.